# How can I convert this JSON from PHP to a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to assign a json array to a javascript array so that my JS functions can access the array.
So I have an ajax call to MySQL db to get a JSON array of data:

```
var data = [];
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"position.php",
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(jsonarray){
                data=$.parseJSON(jsonarray);
               }
     });
```

position.php:

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';  

$sql = "SELECT pid, posX, posY FROM posTable;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$myrows = $result->num_rows;
$return=array();

if ($result->num_rows>0){

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){      
     $return[]=array((int)$row['pid'],(int)$row['posX'],(int)$row['posY']);        
     }

}else{
echo "[]";
}
echo json_encode($return);
$conn->close();
?>
```

This gives an output like this:

```
[[1,749,1000],[2,855,986],[3,955,946],[4,1037,934],[5,1111,912]]
```

And from this I want the following two dimensional array so that I can access its memebers in this form:

```
data[i][j]

data => [[1,749,1000],[2,855,986],[3,955,946],[4,1037,934],[5,1111,912]]
```

However when I execute the code I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will automatically parse a JSON response **before** populating the success function's first argument.

`$.parseJSON(jsonarray);` calls `toString()` on your array and then tries to parse it as JSON, which it isn't (because `Array.prototype.toString()` doesn't convert to JSON).

Just don't try to parse it again.

Comment: I now assigned jsonarray to data without the json parsing and it takes care of the error. How can I see that data is now properly two dimensional? i.e. how can I see that data is truly of the form data[i][j]

Comment: `console.log` is the usual choice for inspecting an element

Comment: When I try this, I get 0 undefined error:
    ` for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
   alert(data[i][j]);

   }
  }`
UPDATE: From console I can see that data is indeed a 2D array

Comment: Are you sure you get an undefined **error** and not just an alert where the value is a stringified `undefined` value?

Comment: I get : **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**
Alert does not pop up

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context. This does seem to be a different problem though, so I suggest that you ask a new question with a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve showing how you are running that code and when.

Comment: It now works when I place the for loops inside the ajax call (within the success function). I have no idea why this is yet I defined **data** outside the ajax call.

Comment: Amazing find and answer, that one! +1